# Can Doxygen project brief contain link?

Tags: doxygen, configuration-files, documentation-generation

I am writing my Doxyfile configuration and was wondering if I can include a link within the `PROJECT_BRIEF`. I have tried HTML and Markdown syntax, but it appears to only accept plaintext. Is there a way to add simple markup to the `PROJECT_BRIEF`?

```
PROJECT_BRIEF = "Project heavily inspired by <a href='https://example.com'>Other Project</a>"
```

[image: Output shows HTML syntax verbatim]

```
PROJECT_BRIEF = "Project heavily inspired by [Other Project](https://example.com)"
```

[image: Output shows Markdown syntax verbatim]

My system currently has Doxygen 1.8.17 installed.

Comment: The problem you encounter here is that the `PROJECT_BRIEF` is not really processed by doxygen, the only processing that is done is converting the string to valid syntax, for HTML this includes converting `<` into `&lt;` (as in HTML cannot conain `<` in text and here doxygen does not know whether the `<` is part of a tag or not as it doesn't really process it. For other output types (e.g. LaTeX) again other restrictions are valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to accomplish this using a custom `HTML_HEADER`.

1. Generate default templates (we will only be looking at header.html).

```bash
doxygen -w html header.html footer.html stylesheet.css Doxyfile
rm footer.html stylesheet.css
```

2. Modify `header.html`.

   - Find the existing `$projectbrief` tag.

     ```html
     <div id="projectbrief">$projectbrief</div>
     ```
   - Add some javascript to "unescape" the HTML.

     ```html
     <script>
       function htmlDecode(input) {
         var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(input, "text/html");
         return doc.documentElement.textContent;
       }
       document.getElementById("projectbrief").innerHTML = htmlDecode("$projectbrief");
     </script>
     ```
3. Modify `Doxyfile` to use new `HTML_HEADER`

```
HTML_HEADER = header.html
```

4. Admire your markup!
   [image: Output shows correctly formatted tag]

Note: Other output types (e.g. LaTeX) also can similarly use custom header files.

Additionally, Markdown syntax is theoretically possible using any number of JavaScript Markdown parsers.